# Next Auth Admin Role

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I use next-auth latest and firebase as the db. I want to fetch the rest API and receive an array with the emails (that can have the admin role). The problem is that when I fetch the API in the [...nextauth].js file , the function returns undefined.

I tried everything , spent 3 hours asking Chat GPT to solve it , but the variable that awaits the fetching is still undefined.

**[...nextauth].js**

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

async function getUsersWithAdminRole() {
  const res = await fetch(
    "https://blog-d9dcf-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/data/admins.json"
  );
  const data = await res.json();
  console.log(data);
  const admins = Object.values(data).map((admin) => admin.email);
  return admins;
}

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async session(session, user) {
      const admins = await getUsersWithAdminRole();
      console.log("admins:", admins);
      console.log("user:", user);
      const isAdmin =
        user && admins.includes((admin) => admin == user.token.email);
      session.role = isAdmin ? "admin" : "user";
      console.log("session:", session);
      return session;
    },
  },
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
});
```